# Export a single frame as a new Blender model

Tags: modeling, export, keyframes

I've got a horrendously complex ship model that has two states that I wish to work with. Unfortunately I managed to produce 76 frames of animation - they looked smooth when I first did it. However I knew nothing about the origin business and I've gotten into great difficulties with Blender resetting where different objects are when I save and reopen the file.

What I wish to do is save frame 1 as a new model and frame 76 as a new model, then figure out how to reset all the geometry so all the wings and things are not everywhere.

Is there a way I can do this? I've found nothing obvious yet.

The horrendously complicated bit is the fact that it's over a million triangles - probably shouldn't be - but I didn't know how to get the detail I wanted any other way at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only one mesh, no matter how much poly count it has, the procedure will be quite easy.

1. Make a backup file of your ship.
2. In "on work" file, duplicate the ship.
3. Set timeline on 1 keyframe and delete all keyframes for original ship (this way you will get the ship in 1 frame position)
4. Set timeline on 76 keyframe and delete all keyframes for second ship (this way you will get second ship in 76 frame position).
   You probably would want to have this ships on different layers for better performance. From this point you can proceed with whatever you want to achieve with this project.